# docker-compose up fails when docker-compose run is successful

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to dockerize my Django-postgres app and run 2 commands using docker-compose
My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python app/manage.py migrate && python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

and my settings .py has the following database code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

My db and web containers are up when I run:

```
docker-compose run web python app/manage.py migrate
docker-compose run web python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

it fails with the error:

> ```
> web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> web_1  |        Is the server running on host "db" (172.23.0.2) and accepting
> web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

Can anyone please help me find where I am going wrong?

Comment: Possibly your db docker image comes up but postgres is not started by the time Django starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here that `docker-compose up` does not wait untill the `db` is running.

you may use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) , see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

example :

```
command: ["/code/wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "MY_CODE"]
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh \
    && chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

or sleeping in your command:

```
command: bash -c "sleep 60 && python app/manage.py migrate && python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

**PS**

I can see the you use `ADD . /code/` and `volumes: - .:/code` , so you need to remove `ADD . /code/` since it will be overwrite from the volume, but then you need to install `wait-for-it.sh` in another path